# Transpiling/code generation - declaration of variables issue

Tags: compiler-construction, antlr, abstract-syntax-tree, transpiler, implicit-declaration

I have recently been working on ANTLR and Java and I built a simple grammar that parses this code and generates an AST. I also wrote a built-in interpreter to execute this code and it seems to work well:

Some notes on my toy language:

- My language has only variable one type of "double"
- All variables are implicitly declared on assignment.
- All variables have global scope. I.e. I can use a variable after it is assigned even outside the block in which it is assigned.

```
/* A sample program */
BEGIN
    j := 1;
    WHILE j <= 5 DO
        PRINT "ITERATION NO: "; PRINTLN j;
        sumA1 := 0;
        WHILE 1 = 1 DO 
            PRINT "Enter a number, 0 to quit: ";
            i := INPUT;
            IF i = 0 THEN
                BREAK;
            ENDIF
            sumA1 := ADD sumA1, i;
        ENDWHILE
        j := ADD j, 1;
        PRINT "The sum is: "; PRINTLN sumA1;
    ENDWHILE
    j := MINUS j;
    PRINTLN j;
END
```

I then wrote the code generation functions into the AST to output this to C from my AST class and I get this result (beautified):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
  double j;
  j = 1.00000;
  while (j <= 5.0) {
    printf("ITERATION NO: ");
    printf("%g\n", j);
    double sumA1;
    sumA1 = 0.00000;
    while (1.0 == 1.0) {
      printf("Enter a number, 0 to quit: ");
      double i;
      scanf("%lf", & i);
      if (i == 0.0) {
        break;
      }
      sumA1 = sumA1 + i;
    }
    j = j + 1.00000;
    printf("The sum is: ");
    printf("%g\n", sumA1);
  }
  j = -j;
  printf("%g\n", j);
}
```

During the code generation, I am checking first if the variable name is available in the HashMap. For assignment statements/input statements, I add the variable declaration just before assignment, as you can see. For usage of variables other than assignment, I throw an Exception for non-initializing of variable before usage.

All well and good. The above code works for this example, since in my source program I am not using any variable outside the scope in which it is declared.

But there is one issue. Since I am initializing certain variables inside the blocks (like `while` they cannot be used outside the scope), I need a way to collect all the variables used in my source program as global in C (or at least on top of the main() function). Declaring variables just before usage in C will cause valid programs in the source language to fail to compile in C if there is usage of the variable in my program outside of the block.

I thought I can solve it by first resolving all the variables and declaring them at the start of the C program and then generating code.

But if I update the symbol table (HashMap) before generating the code, I won't have a way to know if the variable is actually assigned before usage.

What is the best way to re-design this to ensure that:

- the code generator should check for assignment before usage. I.e. if it finds a usage before assignment, it should throw an exception/compilation error.
- at the same time, all variables in my code should be available as global in the C generated source. So even usage of a variable outside the block is possible if it is assigned before in an inner block, since in my source language it is acceptable.

It is the first time I am attempting something like this. Please provide me pointers to any possible solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the general case, detecting use before assignment is impossible. Consider the following (not very good) C code:

```
int sum;          /* uninitialised */
for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
  if (check(i)) sum = 0;
  sum += val[i];  /* Is sum initialised here? */
  process(sum);
}
```

If `check(i)` is, say, `i % 10 == 0`, then `sum` will certainly be initialised. But if it is `i % 10 == 1`, then `sum` is used uninitialised in the first iteration. In general, whether `sum` is used uninitialised depends on the value of `check(0)`. But there may be no way to know what that is. `check()` might be an external function. Or its return value might be dependent on input. Or it might be based on a difficult computation.

That doesn't mean you shouldn't try to detect the problem. You could use [symbolic execution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_execution), for example, to try to compute a conservative estimate of undefined use. You could throw an exception if you could prove undefined use, and issue a warning if you can't prove that all uses are defined. (Many compilers use a variant of this technique.) That might be an interesting exercise in control-flow analysis.

But for a real-world solution, given that all variables are numeric, I'd suggest just automatically initialising all variables to 0, as part of the language semantics.

Comment: I agree with your assessment. Usage before initialization is a potential fundamental design flaw, rather than a flaw in the semantic structure of the program, so may be impossible to solve at that level. My question was regarding how to collect all the assignment statements in my (source) grammar and declare them as variables at the top of the function in C. In my Toy Programming language, since execution is top/down in a predefined manner, checking for usage before initialization is relatively simple: any reference to the variable before it is assigned is simply an error/exception at runtime.

Comment: @hari: Looking at your example program, I fail to see why my example wouldn't be a valid program in your Toy Language. But it's not a big deal.

Comment: I have solved the lesser problem though, that is generating code for declaring the C variables at the top of the main () function rather than inside the nodes. You're right about the bigger problem. However in my Toy Language interpreter, any use of uninitialized variable simply interrupts the program with an Exception at runtime since the variable would not be found as a key in the HashMap if there is no initialization. The generated C code might lead to potential problems though.

Comment: in my Toy language, I don't have an support for function calling also.

Comment: @hari: It doesn't have to be a real function. It's just a placeholder for a computation. The computation could be arbitrarily difficult (factor a Mersenne prime, for example.)

Comment: OK. got the point. But as I stated earlier, in my interpreter if any variable is not defined on the HashMap and it is used, the program throws an Exception. There is no declaration and assignment separately. So use cannot (by definition) precede assignment (implicit declaration).

Comment: @hari. OK, fair enough. It's your language. :-)

Comment: I have put my own answer to the original question, but your point regarding uninitialized variables remains a good point as far as the generated code is concerned. Perhaps the only solution to ensure correct code generation is to (a) have explicit variable declaration in my language and mimic the behaviour of C in so far as uninitialized variables go or (b) implement scoping rules in my programming language, similar to C.

Comment: @hari: history shows that language designers  who didn't start with lexical scoping eventually regret it. Look at Perl, for example.

Answer (score 0):

I have kind of solved it by removing variable declarations from the individual assignment nodes and just adding the variable used in the assignment node into the global hashmap, and then generated the declarations after running through the tree.

It kind of works like this:

- Walk the AST. If I come across an usage of variable (other than in an assignment/input statement, generate an exception/error.
- If I come across an assignment/input statement, add the variable to the global hashmap. But don't declare it in the code generation for the particular node.
- After generating the entire code - run through the global hashmap and generate the declarations
- Put together the main program by concatenating the declaration statements and the generated code.

But I realized that, this can lead to potential problems where a variable might be initialized inside an IF block and used outside. If the program has executed the IF block, then no problem, but if the IF block is skipped then I get an exception in my interpreter, but the code generation in C still works properly. However, the output in the C program is an uninitialized variable if the IF block is not executed.

Take for example (in my code)

```
BEGIN
   i := INPUT;
   IF i < 10 THEN
      j := MUL i, 10;
   ENDIF
   PRINT j;
END
```

which spits out this C code (prettified)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   double i;
   double j;
   scanf("%lf", &i);
   if (i < 10.0)
   {
      j = i *10.0000;
   }
   printf("%g\n", j);
}
```

In such a scenario, my built-in interpreter will throw an exception if the `IF` block is not reached and compiled i.e. when `i >= 10` (since `j` will be left uninitialized). However, the equivalent C code is generated and compiled properly, but the `j` will be an uninitialized variable leading to a runtime behaviour.

But for now, I think I can accept this behaviour, since in any case, use of potentially uninitialized variable is a problem with the design of the program itself.

I suppose the other alternative is to initialize the variable with implicit NULL (or NaN) value for uninitialized and check for that instead.